# Subversion: how to synchronize $Id$ in various branches of the repository?

Tags: svn

I have repository with many branches and all source files have `$Id$`. When I change one file on trunk I have to change it also on specific branch from the same repository. If I simply copy modified file to specific branch and commit it then `$Id$` will have new value. From this time the only difference between source file in trunk and source file in branch is value in `$Id$` and file compare utilities will show it as difference.

Is there any way to have the same `$Id` in both trunk and branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you commit to both trunk and branch in the same commit that would probably do it. The problem about compare utilities seeing a difference could be mitigated by using the svn comparison utilities which should understand that there is no difference.

Comment: Can you show examples from command line? I also use TortoiseSVN, but their `TortoiseMerge.exe` seems to work with files only, not comparing directories, and it also shows that line with `$Id$` is different (I cannot find "Ignore $Id$ value" option).

Comment: @MichałNiklas I'm not sure about TortoiseSVN, the information I got came from the first response to http://wordaligned.org/articles/keyword-substitution-just-say-no . They're using svn diff, so perhaps TortoiseSVN isn't stripping the keyword substitution for TortoiseMerge (I'm assuming you're right clicking and selecting diff or diff with previous version, something like that).